# Does Orthodox Judaism endorse or prescribe exercises and acts to help counteract negative influences or inner spiritual issues and conflicts?

Tags: mussar-ethics, chinuch-education, soul, evil-inclination

I know this question sounds kind of "New Age" in terms of theme but I was genuinely curious if Orthodox Judaism has any figures who endorsed such topics or books which discussed the topic (either in an historical or contemporary standard)

Basically, religious/spiritual exercises or practices which act to remove negative influences from one's environment or body or psyche. Things of that nature.

I'm speaking to ideas outside of the mainstream exercises of Kashrut, Mikvah washing, and things of that nature.

Comment: I'm uncertain what you're aiming at. As a general rule, Orthodox Judaism encourages a continuous constant awareness that G-d is watching every action that you perform and every thought that you have and that you are ultimately accountable to G-d for any wrongdoing. Thus, for millenia (long before "Orthodoxy" was a term,) rabbis have constantly enacted various "fences" to prevent transgression. They also encourage study as a means to guard against idling in both action and thought.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3316534/jewish/9-Sivan.htm

Comment: Could you give us examples of exercises you are looking for. Your question seems vague/too broad.

Comment: Yes, learning Torah ..

Answer (score -1):

1. Orthodox Judaism is a huge diversity of views, opinions, and approaches. It can not possibly be generalized. There's also a vast difference between the Israeli Haredi community where there are very few influences of the environment, and the American Haredi community that deals with the immense amount of environmental influence.
2. The actual practice reflects the need to confront that influence. The general approach in Israeli OJ communities is "**אם פגע בך מנוול זה משכהו לבית המדרש**" (Kiddushin 30b), i.g. all problems can be solved solely by learning Torah and learning Torah more. The almost total separation of the Torah scholars from the outer world incl. the lack of the need of working outside allows that. It still depends on every Yeshivah's tradition but in general, the "importance" of Mussar is not big.
3. The Orthodox communities in which their members work outside and live among the Gentiles put a serious emphasis on learning Mussar - the ways of coping with those influences.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I esp. like your #1 point, as I think many people overlook this. I would add that there are almost similar situations in "shtetl"-like communities in the U.S. such as Williamsburg, Boro Park, etc. where Hareidm are a majority and set up "isolationist" practices to a large extent. I'm not ready to vote, here, as I don't know if this answers OP question. Not to do with you. The question is quite vague.